# Recuperar dato de stdClass Object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Utilizo el framework codeigniter, llamo de la vista un dato seleccionado de una lista desplegable de la siguiente manera:

```
$nombre_activo = $this->input->post('tipo_activo',true);
```

luedo con este dato hago una consulta a la base de datos para que me traiga el id del nombre seleccionado.

```
public function id_activo($nombre_activo)
    {
        $query=$this->db
                ->select("id_tipo_activo")
                ->from("tipo_activo")
                ->where(array("nombre_tipo_activo"=>$nombre_activo))
                ->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();exit;        
        return $query->row();            
    }
```

luego en el controlador estoy llamando lo que me retorna la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$id_activo = $this->activo_model->id_activo($nombre_activo);
```

necesito guardar el dato obtenido de la consulta en una variable tipo string, pero lo que me esta guardando en la variable $id_activo es lo siguiente

> stdClass Object ( [id_tipo_activo] => 1 )

como puedo recuparer el 1 de esa clase std ?

agradezco me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdClass Object como su clase lo indica es un objeto por lo cual puede ser tratado como tal, si tú haces esto

```
$nombre_activo->id_tipo_activo
```

traerás el valor de dicha propiedad